# UIButton Programmatically get Default Highlighted Style

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I searched for this problem for a while and couldn't find anything about it, but eventually figured out my mistake, so I figured I'd post it here to help anyone with the same situation.

When creating `UIButton`s in Interface Builder, it automatically styles them for the highlight state (If you press and hold the button, it looks dim/lighter in whatever color you set it as); however, I was trying to create a button programmatically (just a normal text button) and wasn't achieving this result. If I pressed and held the button, the appearance was unchanged, although the button still worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that I was initializing the button with

```
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
```

instead of

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeSystem];
```

Which is apparently the best-practice way of initializing a `UIButton`.

Comment: Solved my issue of programmatic buttons without a depressed state onTouchUpInside.